# Angularjs seems to throw meaningless errors

Tags: angularjs

I keep get error logs like this in the console:

```
ReferenceError {}      angular.min.js:60
  (anonymous function) angular.min.js:60
  (anonymous function) angular.min.js:51
  (anonymous function) angular.min.js:88
  m                    angular.min.js:6
  e.$broadcast         angular.min.js:88
  (anonymous function) angular.min.js:80
  i                    angular.min.js:76
  i                    angular.min.js:76
  (anonymous function) angular.min.js:76
  e.$eval              angular.min.js:86
  e.$digest            angular.min.js:84
  e.$apply             angular.min.js:86
  e                    angular.min.js:92
  o                    angular.min.js:95
  q.onreadystatechange angular.min.js:96
```

I can usually debug it myself, but these stack traces are awfully meaningless.. am I doning somthing wrong or is this just the way it is?

Comment: I wonder if using the non-minified version of Angular would provide more helpful information in the console?

Comment: A little better, but still meaningless to me.

`ReferenceError {} angular.js:5582
(anonymous function) angular.js:5582
(anonymous function) angular.js:4679
Scope.$broadcast angular.js:8092
(anonymous function) angular.js:7250
wrappedCallback angular.js:6650
wrappedCallback angular.js:6650
(anonymous function) angular.js:6687
Scope.$eval angular.js:7840
Scope.$digest angular.js:7707
Scope.$apply angular.js:7926
done angular.js:8933
completeRequest angular.js:9073
xhr.onreadystatechange`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i quote the trace provider :

```
ReferenceError {}      angular.min.js:60
  (anonymous function) angular.min.js:60
  (anonymous function) angular.min.js:51
  (anonymous function) angular.min.js:88
```

a few things , your error seems related to $http or $resource and AJAX. if you are using anonymous callbacks, name them

for instance :

```
$http.get("/blop")
  .success(function _successGet(){})
  .error(function _errorGet(){})
```

that way , you'll have some clues about the stack trace. instead of (anonymous function) you'll get a ref to _successGet or _errorGet.